# Показ кнопки скрыть, при открытом списке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется множество списков, в которых показываются максимум 7 строчек. После каждого списка есть кнопка "Ещё", при нажатии на которую, открывается весь оставшийся список к уже существующему (other_li). Вот код:

```
<div class="work-title-category-item">
    <h2>Тексты</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Сценарии</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Резюме</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Статьи</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Редактирование</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Контент менеджер</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Стихи, сказки, эссе</a></li>
            <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Помощь, мануал</a></li>
            <span class="other_li">
                <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Создание субтитров</a></li>
                <li><a href="work-create-2.php" title="">Бизнес-тексты</a></li>
            </span>
            <li class="local-cat local-cat-show" id="more">Ещё..</li>
            <li class="local-cat local-cat-sh" id="shadow">Скрыть</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
// Активация скрытого меню при нажатии "Ещё"
let prev = null;
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (!el.classList.contains("local-cat")) return false;
  let other = el.parentElement.querySelector(".other_li");
  if (prev === other) {
    other.style.display = "none";
    prev = null;
    return false;
  }
  if (prev) prev.style.display = "none";
  other.style.display = "block";
  prev = el.parentElement.querySelector(".other_li");
});
```

Возможно всё работает не очень хорошо, но пока у меня имеется код, чтобы кнопка "Ещё" исчезала при открытом списке, а "Скрыть" появлялась, но проблема заключается в том, что срабатывает код на все списки, а нажимал только на одном. Вижу единственный выход - прописывать каждому списку к "Ещё" и "Скрыть" другие классы, а к ним постоянно копировать код с новыми классами. Плохая идея, поэтому и обратился сюда, за более нормальным решением. Вот кстати код:

```
// Показ кнопки "скрыть" при раскрытом меню
$('.local-cat-show').click(function() {
  $(this).css("display","none");
  $('.local-cat-sh').css("display","initial");
});
$('.local-cat-sh').click(function() {
  $(this).css("display","none");
  $('.local-cat-show').css("display","initial");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.local-cat-show').click(function() {
  $(this).css("display","none");
  $(this).closest("ul").find('.local-cat-sh').css("display","initial");
});
$('.local-cat-sh').click(function() {
  $(this).css("display","none");
  $(this).closest("ul").find('.local-cat-show').css("display","initial");
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло